# Download Video MP4 file from download URL

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to download a video file (MP4) sitting in Cisco Webex server with C#. The URL I have is a download URL which is not exactly file location. Download URL is actually getting browser to download video file.
I tried 'WebClient' but with no luck. Mine is a console application, therefore I cannot use 'HttpWebRequest' and add the MIME type to IIS. Below is the code that I tried using:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();  
client.DownloadFile("https://webex.com/lsr.php?RCID=9853e32d921d", @"C:\\Video.mp4");
```

For now, with my code I am starting an instance of the browser with 'Process.Start("URL")' and have changed the default download location. I know this is not the correct solution therefore I request suggestions.

Comment: What happens if you use `client.DownloadFile...`?

Comment: The link doesn't work for me. Do you have to provide some login to get to the video?

Comment: Stefan - When I use "client.DownloadFile", it is actually downloading 8KB MP4 file and when I am trying to open it with media player, it is giving me codec not available error. I believe it is just downloading HTML content of download URL page and not the real MP4 file.

Comment: venerik - I actually removed some contents from the link as this link has business sensitive data. I put is there just for the reference of what I tried.

Comment: I am still waiting for any proposed solution

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you're still looking for an answer to this or not but I was recently looking for something similar. I wanted to download a video from my web page to the client's browser from my server. I did this and it is successfully downloading.

```
var fileName = Path.GetFileName( filePath );
HttpResponseBase.Response.ClearContent();
this.Response.ClearHeaders();
this.Response.ContentType = type;
this.Response.AppendHeader( "Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName );
this.Response.BinaryWrite( System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes( filePath ) );
this.Response.End();
```

I hope it helps!